# Number method on new Date() in JavaSctipt

Tags: javascript

The Number() method can be used to convert Javascript variables to numbers.
But what does the output of `Number(new Date())` signify?

Comment: timestamp in milliseconds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is equivalent to `new Date().getTime()`, number of milliseconds since [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: it's more equivalent to new Date().valueOf(); clobber getTime and see for yourself...

Comment: @dandavis: Strictly speaking, yes: `Number()` invokes `.valueOf()`. However, [MDN on `.valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf): "This method is functionally equivalent to the `Date.prototype.getTime()` method."

Comment: @Amadan—MDN is a public wiki, anyone can contribute. It's not an authority, ECMA-262 is. If you follow the trail of [*`Number ([value])`*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.1.1), you end up at [*`[[DefaultValue]] (hint: number)`*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8), which calls [*valueOf*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.8), which returns the Date object's [*time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5) (i.e. milliseconds since epoch). *getTime*, *valueOf*, `+`, etc. all do the same thing.

Comment: @RobG: The same ECMA spec also says of `getTime` that it returns this time value. Thus, functionally equivalent. Who cares who says it, if they say the same thing?